# How to install Tesseract and Leptonica with header files on Windows

Tags: windows, tesseract, vcpkg

I have an cross platform application that requires Tesseract and Leptonica to work. Building it on Linux was a piece of cake, Windows seems to be way more difficult.

The problem that I have is that I need the dlls and the header files. When I install Tesseract via vcpkg I don't get the header files. Then I've tried building Tesseract from source, I get the dlls and header files but not the header files for Leptonica. Before I go down the rabbit hole and start building Leptonica from source, which all together probably requires an hour of build time I came here to check if anyone has another idea.

Does anyone have a solution for this?